# Why isn't my drop down box showing when navigation bar is hovered?

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover, dropdown

I created a navigation bar where its supposed to display a drop down box whenever "drug advocacy" is hovered. Yet even though I hover over it, it only changes its color like the other menus and doesn't show the drop down box like I expected it to. Here's the code

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div class="navbar">
      <h1 class="logo">BE AWARE</h1>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown">Drug Advocacy</a>
            <div class="dropdownda">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Drug Awareness</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Types of Drugs</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Abuse and Prevention</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      .navbar {
        background-color: darkgray;
        height: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 0 3%;
      }

      .navbar ul {
        display: flex;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      .navbar ul li {
        padding: 10px 25px;
        position: relative;
      }

      .navbar ul li a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
      
      .navbar ul li a.dropdown {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

      .navbar ul li a:hover {
        color: purple;
      }
      
      /*This is the drop down box section of CSS*/
      .dropdownda {
        display: none;
        }
    
      .navbar ul li a.dropdown:hover .dropdownda {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        background-color: darkgray;
      }

      .navbar ul li a.dropdown:hover .dropdownda ul {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .navbar ul li a.dropdown:hover .dropdownda ul li {
        width: 180px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
```

I thought there was just some missing or wrong hierarchy in the CSS and HTML, or maybe a wandering typo somewhere. But as of right now, I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong with my code (most likely the CSS but not sure). I'm not really experienced so I might just be coding it wrong.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<li>` elements cannot be directly nested in one another.

Comment: In your CSS `a.dropdown:hover .dropdownda` needs to incorporate a plus (+, the sibling selector) as in: `a.dropdown:hover + .dropdownda`. **And** the last 2 <li> (contact, gallery) need to be below the closing </li> of 'Drug Advocacy'.